# Web project Debugging & Coding in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a web project in Visual Studio.

When at work i can start the project in debug mode (F5), and set break points. Edit the Code Behind or asp controls. When pressing F5, this will refresh and my new code will be represented.

At my home computer i can edit, i can press F5, but my changes will not be shown. And the debugger will step through the code like it does not realize that it has come some new code.

Has anyone experienced this before? This is not the first time I have seen this, but i cant for the life of me figure out how to make it refresh....

Any pointers will be welcome :)

Edit:

Could this by any chance have something to do about the project type? Or the compilation of the web project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out why this worked as it did.

The project type i had chosen for my project was ASP.NET WEb Forms Application. This implies that the project will compile and be run from an DLL file.

To rebuild this everytime there is made a change is not possible, so it doesn't.

I changed the project type and buildt a Web Site instead. This kind of project does not compile into a DLL, but is rather run on the fly from the files that i code. Because of this i can make changes to my files, hit f5 and it will automatically reload with the new content.